# React Native CLI - Creating a button in a ScrollView

Tags: react-native

Hey I'm just starting out with React Native CLI.

I want to have a button which will add an item in the ScrollView. And the new Item should lead to a new Screen when you press it. But I don't have an idea how to make this nor do I know how to google that xD. Does anyone know how I can make this?

I just have a button which leads to another screen when pressing it.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Look up React Native Navigation

Answer (score 0):

First you have to clear few things and make the logic.

1)Either you want to save that item datathen show it in scroll view, make it Pressable and then u can navigate to a different screen.

Or

2. You just want to show the data in the scroll view. Once you reload, the data is gone. So that's my bro (In my opinion) is of no use.

For the first step .
You need to store the data in a storage and then fetch it in a scroll view,
make it Pressable and navigate to a different screen.

(hint: If you want to make it Pressable then you can fetch the data into a card component and then call that component in a scroll view).

Now grab your keyboard and start searching on it.